# Grails default methods in controller

Tags: grails

I am having a problem saving a domain instance in grails; The domainInstance that's passed to the default update method in my controller is NULL. The GSP page I am submitting from is not the default edit page. I have certain values from DB that need to be saved. I have the form tag defined on the page that contains the values I need to submit, as follows.
        `<g:form id="sampleForm" url="[resource:domainInstance, controller:'cntrlrName', action:'update']" method="PUT" >`

I also have a version field which looks like this.
        `<g:hiddenField name="version" value="${domainInstance?.version}" />`

My g:submit is as follows
        `<g:actionSubmit action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />`

Why is my domain instance null? What am I missing?

Comment: please show some code for the community to help you

Comment: what is your problem, and post your controller code.

Comment: Sorry. I noticed that the code didn't show up in my problem description. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 2):

This is the common mistake one could make. The attribute `id` in `<g:form>` tag is not the `id` attribute of HTML tags but it is the id to use in the link for default mapping of Grails i.e.

```
"/$controller/$action/$id" {}
```

So change your tag as:

```
<g:form name="sampleForm" id="${domainInstance.id}" controller="cntrlrName" action="update" method="PUT">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the domainInstance but I feel it is better practice to pass the id instead of the object. Try passing the id of the domain instance and then reading the object in the controller.

```
<g:form name="sampleForm" action="action" controller="controller" id="${domainInstance.id}" ></g:form>
```

// in controller

```
def resource = Domain.read(params.id)
```

another approach could be to pass the domainInstance as a hiddenField

```
<g:hiddenField name="resource" value="$domainInstance" />
```